# Pontiac Bonneville shakes

Tags: pontiac

I have a 95 Non-supercharge Pontiac Bonneville. When I am traveling at a speed at which produces 2000 ± 500 RPMs the engine shakes. An almost sputtering/slippage but remarkably different at the same time they just serve as a good verbal illustration. Also, occasionally when having to accelerate quickly to get on the highway through short ramps (40 - 75 in 125 feet) it will completely loose performance, then it will come back. I'm a college student on a budget who rides a motorcycle 96% of the year and can't afford to throw parts at it until it works, please tell me why you suspect the trouble and how to test it first I have a multimeter but have only had the opportunity of learning to use it for continuity testing. If you tell me how to set the multi meter to test it then I'll gladly learn new skills. And if someone's answer is further down the troubleshooting g tree let me know the order of importance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given how fragile the MAF is in those vehicles, that'd be the first thing I'd check.  I've heard similar stories many a time and a sizeable percentage came back to ultimately be the Mass Air Flow sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms point to a transmission fault, most probably the stator assembly in the torque convertor. A prelimanary check would be the trans oil level, as per your drivers handbook. If this makes no improvement you will need a check on your trans at a repair shop. Check to see if they can do a check and report, and give you a quote, before committing to any expenditure.